# Prove that the number of pairs (m,n) of integers such that $n^2-3mn+m-n=0$ is two

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

We can write the equation as: $m(1-3n)=n(1-n)$

$m=\frac{n(n-1)}{(3n-1)}$

The denominator leaves a remainder of $2$ when divided by three, so n should either be a multiple of $3$ or leave a remainder $2$ upon dividing by $3$. Beyond that I can't see any patterns. I know two solutions will be $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ but how can we prove that the other solutions don't exist

Comment: Note that $n\,|\,m$.  Write $m=An$ and observe that, if you can divide the resultant expression by $n$, you get a contradiction.

Comment: "$n$ can't be even, unless it's $0$ otherwise the denominator would be odd." --- why can't the denominator $3n-1$ be odd?  You seems to be claiming, for example, $14/7$ is not an integer because $7$ is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $3n - (3n-1) = 1$, it follows that $\gcd(n, 3n-1) = 1$. Thus if $m$ is an integer, $3n - 1 | n - 1$. But $3n - 1 > n - 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: $3n - (3n-1) = 1$, it follows that $\gcd(n, 3n-1) = 1$, how did you derive this?

Comment: $\gcd(a,b) = 1 \iff$ there exist integers $u,v$ such that $au + bv = 1$.

Comment: You can note that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides any linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Since $\gcd(n, 3n - 1)$ divides $1$, it must be equal to $1$.